Magento2.4: How to save custom fields data into customer_entity table when saving customer programatically?
I'm creating a customer programmatically with a customer interface, and custom attributes are saving as expected, but I want those custom attributes value in the customer_entity table also.
My code is this

db_schema.xml

<table name="customer_entity">
   <column name="is_demo" xsi:type="boolean"  default="0" comment="Is Demo"/>
   <column name="sales_agent" xsi:type="varchar"   comment="Sales Agent"/>
</table>

My customer saving logic.
$customer = $this->customerInterfaceFactory->create();
                    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                    $customer->setEmail($data['email']);
                    $customer->setFirstname($data['firstname']);
                    $customer->setLastname($data['lastname']);
                    $customer->setGroupId(1);
                    
                    // my custom fields in customer_entity table
                    $customer->setIsDemo($data['is_demo']);
                    $customer->setSalesAgent($data['sales_agent']);
                    
                    // saving custom attributes

                    if ($data['sales_agent']) {
                        $customer->setCustomAttribute('sales_agent', $data['sales_agent']);
                    }
                    if ($data['is_demo']) {
                        $customer->setCustomAttribute(
                            'is_demo',
                            isset($data['is_demo']) ? 1 : 0
                        );
                    }
                   
                    $hashedPassword = $this->encryptor->getHash($data['password'], true);
                    $this->customerRepository->save($customer, $hashedPassword);
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($data['email'], $data['password']);
                    $this->customerSession->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->customerSession->regenerateId();
                    // these variable for new trial approach
                    $this->checkoutSession->setIsTrial(true);
                    $this->customerSession->setIsTrial(true);


extension_attributes.xml

<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="is_demo" type="int"/>
        <attribute code="sales_agent" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>

but when I do this in my code it says

Error: Call to undefined method
Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::setIsDemo()

How can I save those custom attribute values in the customer_entity  table when saving customers programmatically?

Instead of creating a field using db_scheme.xml , i suggest that create a customer type eav attribute and defining the  attribute type is static  mean 'type' => 'static' in data [catch script.
Example:
<?php

namespace Medline\CustomerHello\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddIsDemoCustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private Config $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var Attribute
     */
    private Attribute $attributeResource;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param Attribute $attributeResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory          $eavSetupFactory,
        Config                   $eavConfig,
        Attribute                $attributeResource
    )
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
    }

    /**
     * Run code inside patch
     * If code fails, patch must be reverted, in case when we are speaking about schema - then under revert
     * means run PatchInterface::revert()
     *
     * If we speak about data, under revert means: $transaction->rollback()
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'is_demo',
            [
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'system' => false,
                'label' => 'IsDemo',
                'source' => null,
                'position' => 900,
                'type' => 'static',
                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'required' => false,
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            'Default',
            'is_demo'
        );

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_demo');
        $attribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit']
        );
        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get array of patches that have to be executed prior to this.
     *
     * Example of implementation:
     *
     * [
     *      \Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Setup\Patch\Patch1::class,
     *      \Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Setup\Patch\Patch2::class
     * ]
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get aliases (previous names) for the patch.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}

If you create an attribute as static then it will save data in the main entity type customer_entity.
